# (Inserting into an Ordered List)

Tags: visual-c++, data-structures

I have to write this program:
Write a program that inserts 25 random integers from 0 to 100 in order in a linked list. The program should calculate the sum of the elements and the floating point average of the elements. 
this is what I have done so far to fill the linked list with random words , but it just repeat a specific integer.

```html
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node* next;
};
node *head;
void randomize()
{
 node *newnode;
 //srand(time(NULL));
 for (int i=0;i<25;i++)
 {
  srand(time(NULL));
  newnode=(node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
  srand(time(NULL));
  int random=rand()%100;
  newnode->data=random;
  newnode->next=head;
  head=newnode;

 }
}
void display()
{
 node *record=head;
 while(record!=NULL)
 {
  cout<<(record->data)<<endl;
  record=record->next;
 }
}
int main()
{
 randomize();
 display();
 getch();
}
```

`>

```
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node* next;
};
node *head;
void randomize()
{
    node *newnode;
    newnode=(node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int i=0;i<25;i++)
    {
        srand(time(NULL));
        int random=rand()%100;
        newnode->data=random;
        newnode->next=head;
        head=newnode;

    }
}
void display()
{
    node *record=head;
    while(record!=NULL)
    {
        cout<<(record->data);
        record=record->next;
    }
}
int main()
{
    randomize();
    display();
    getch();
}
```

Comment: try using your debugger...

Comment: What language? Visual-C++ is for `C` and `C++`

Comment: I've suggested you try to debug. Is there a reason you are unable to do so?

Comment: @functionR :Im writing in visual studio c++

Comment: @mitch : Im new at programming and i need some help to fix the problem

Comment: Are you appending or prepending to the list?

Comment: no Im not appending.I want to have a list with 25 random integers

Comment: You want an ordered list (as title states), but I do not see any comparison in order to put the new node into the list? How do you know the new node value is smaller or bigger than the rest of the list?

Comment: actually this question is from deitel book and here is the question: (Inserting into an Ordered List) Write a program that inserts 25 random integers from 0 to 100 in order in a linked list. The program should calculate the sum of the elements and the floatingpoint average of the elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could spot 3 things:

1. assign head to NULL;
   node *head = NULL;
2. move memory allocation inside for loop
3. use mod by 101 to get random numbers between 0 to
   100

Answer (score 0):

Repeating comes from the `randomize()` method of your code. 
Move the line

```
newnode = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node));
```

into the `for` loop in `randomize()`. By this way you create and prepend a new node to the list.

You have to consider rewriting `randomize()` in order to create an ordered list. For example you should iterate over the current list and find a suitable place for the new node with the random value. Instead of prepend, you can also append which is quite easy for ordered linked lists. You can easily find examples (ordered linked-lists) by the help of Google.